# about tasks in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

in my current code I am using two OpenMP sections, with two threads only
as follows:

```
!$omp parallel NUM_THREADS(2)                                                                                                                                                     
!$omp sections
!$omp section
   do work1
!$omp section
   do work2
!$omp end sections
!$omp end parallel
```

`work1` is more time consuming than `work2`, and because `sections` construct requires both threads to finish their tasks to synchronize, `work1` becomes the limiting step, and one thread is wasted most of the time.

I want to use a more flexible construct such as `task`, but I don't know if it is
possible to do the following and if so, how to do it. First, start with two threads (1 task per thread as in `sections` construct), one solving `work1` and the other `work2`. Second, as soon as the easiest task `work2` is finished, the free thread could be used to speedup `work1`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain with more details what is the work1 and work2. Can you decomposite them into several smaller works (will they be independent or not)?

Comment: inside routine work1 there are several routines that could benefit from using two threads instead of one. But with my legacy code, it would be a bit difficult to separate all routines in small pieces.

Comment: You really should show how does `work1` look like so that it can be speed up by the other thread. In code, not in words. Show more code. Real code, stay away from simplifications.